# Integration on a graph of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know how to prove the following theorem:

> If $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a graph of a $C^1$ function $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, then for a measurable function $g$ on $M$ we have $$\int_M g d\sigma=\int_{\Omega}g(x,f(x))\sqrt{1+|\bigtriangledown f(x)|^2}dx$$

Comment: I don't know where it is you are stuck? Do you know $M$ is set, and an element of $M$ is an n-tuple, $\{ f(x), x\}$ where $x$ is an $n-1$ dimensional vector with components $x_i$. Then because $f(x)$ is a scalar function $\Bbb R^{n-1}$ to $\Bbb R$ $M$ is $n$ dimensional.

Comment: $g$ acts on $M$ so it takes in elements $\{ f(x),x\} \\ \forall x$. Really $g$ is determined for by $x$ so it can be parameterized by $\Bbb R^{n-1}$ instead of $\Bbb R^{n}$. I don't know what $d\sigma$ means though so I can't help you there. Maybe an infitesmal displacement which is generalized to other measures?

Comment: I would give this article a read, especially the multivariable section.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Comment: What is your definition of $\int_M g\ d\sigma$?

Comment: I realize nowadays the battle is already lost on Math StackExchange, but this is a poor question. In fact, there is no question! And you give no context whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent hyperplane to $M$ at a point $(p,f(p))\in M$, $p\in\Omega$, is given by the equation
$$x_n=p_n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f_{.k}(p)(x_k-p_k)\ .$$
A normal of this hyperplane therefore is given by
$$\vec n=\bigl(-f_{.1}(p),-f_{.2}(p),\ldots, f_{.n-1}(p),1\bigr)\ .$$
If $\alpha$ is the angle between $\vec n$ and the $x_n$-axis we then have
$$\cos\alpha={\vec n\cdot(0,\ldots,0,1)\over|\vec n|\cdot 1}={1\over\sqrt{|\nabla f(p)|^2+1}}\ .$$
It follows that the scalar hypersurface element ${\rm d}\sigma$ over the point $p$ is given by 
$${\rm d}\sigma={1\over\cos\alpha}{\rm d}(x)=\sqrt{|\nabla f(p)|^2+1}\>{\rm d}(x)\ ,$$
whereby ${\rm d}(x)$ denotes the $(n-1)$-dimensional area element in $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^{n-1}$, the latter coinciding with the $(n-1)$-dimensional volume element in ${\mathbb R}^{n-1}$.

It follows that, given a "temperature function" $g$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$, we obtain as "total heat energy" present in the hypersurface $M\subset {\mathbb R}^n$ the value
$$\int_M g(x, f(x))\>{\rm d}\sigma=\int_\Omega g(x,f(x))\>\sqrt{|\nabla f(p)|^2+1}\>{\rm d}(x)\ .$$